# Namespace constant thingy for forward slash

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

What’s the .net namespace constant thingy for the forward slash "/"

So instead of:

```
somePath + "/" + someFile
```

I can do:

```
somePath + .net.namespace.forwardslash + someFile
```

Not really much difference but maybe neater?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) is what you want i think.

BTW, a saner way to do it is to use [System.IO.Path.Combine(somePath,someFile)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx).

Comment: so many upvotes and even an accept for a misleading answer. The Path.DirectorySeparatorChar returns "a platform-specific character used to separate directory levels in a path string that reflects a hierarchical file system organization" (MSDN) - therefore it WON'T be the forward slash in most .net cases. However, if you are just asking how to concatenate directory path and file name in a safe way, then the answer is correct (although the question is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a forward slash if that's what you need, but if you're trying to combine a file name and a path, just use System.IO.Path.Combine().

Comment: This is not correct: System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar. But I didn't downvote because you mentioned Path.Combine, though.

Comment: He is correct. On Windows Path.DirectorySeparatorChar returns the backslash, in Mono it will be probably a slash when running on an unixoid environment. Using Path.Combine is the correct approach.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is the correct answer.  OP wants the "**constant** thingy for forward slash".  On account of that 'platform specific' bit @MarcWittke mentions in the other answer, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar is not only unlikely to be forward slash, but is also not constant and errors out when you try to use it in one (as does Path.Combine()). tl;dr The forward slash constant is "/"

Answer (score 0):

You should go with `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`

Answer (score 0):

Forward Slash is actually [AltDirectorySeparatorChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.7.2)